# how to get value Http Get Request with parameter in flutter

Tags: api, flutter

I already create Get Request with 3 parameter in postman
[image]

I tried this in flutter but it didnt showing the data to listview
I already tried with hard code its working fine. but when i input this value, it didnt working at all.
Here is my FetchData

```
 Future<LoanModel> _fetchData() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    final response =
    await http.get('http://192.168.0.23/edufund-api/Api/loansimulation.php?periodtime=$periodtime&interestpermonth=$interestpermonth&loanamountrequest=$loanamountrequest'); //error but working when insert the value
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        for (Map i in data) {
          _loanmodel.add(LoanModel.fromJson(i));
        }
        loading = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

and here is my simulators function

```
  static Future<LoanResult> simulators({String periodtime, String interestpermonth, String loanamountrequest,String url}) async  {
    var url = "http://192.168.0.23/edufund-api/Api/loansimulation.php?periodtime=" + periodtime + "&interestpermonth=" + interestpermonth + "&loanamountrequest=" +loanamountrequest;
    final response = await http.get(url,headers:{"Content-Type":
    "application/json"},
    );
    var res = LoanResult.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);
    print(response.body); //value get in response.body
    return res;
  }
```

How to handle http Get with parameter in flutter?
The result i get it flutter
[image]

Here is my API

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
include_once '../Database/database.php';
include_once '../Controller/users.php';

// get data from query string api json
$periodtime= $_GET['periodtime'];
$interestpermonth= $_GET['interestpermonth'];
$loanamountrequest = $_GET['loanamountrequest'];


$balance = $loanamountrequest;
$principal = 0;
$installments = 0;

$resultbalance = 0;
$resultprincipal = 0;
$resultinterest = 0;
$resultinstallments = 0;

if($periodtime != null){
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $periodtime; $x++) {
        $resultprincipal = $loanamountrequest / $periodtime;
        $resultinterest = $interestpermonth * $loanamountrequest / 100;

        if($x == 0){
            $balance -= $principal;
            $principal = 0;
            $interest = 0;
            $installments = 0;
        }
        else{
            $interest = $resultinterest;
            $balance -= $resultprincipal;
            $principal = $resultprincipal;
            $installments = $principal + $interest;
        }

        // change to decimal point 2 digits comma behind number.
        $formatinterest =  number_format($interest,2);
        $formatbalance = number_format($balance,2);
        $formatprincipal = number_format($principal,2);
        $formatinstallments = number_format($installments, 2);



        $simulation_arr[]=array(
            "No" => $x,
            "interest" => $formatinterest,
            "balance" => $formatbalance,
            "principal" => $formatprincipal,
            "Installment" => $formatinstallments,
            "Status" => true
        );

    }
}
else{
    $simulation_arr=array(
        "status" => false,
        "message" => "Invalid Get Simulation Credit. Please Input the period time!",
    );
}

// make it json format
print_r(json_encode($simulation_arr));

?>
```

Comment: Check the console. Did you get any errors? If so, please post.

Comment: i got this error : Error FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <br/> Flutter

Comment: but with hard code, its working fine. But thats not based on parameter value

Comment: Can you post the request and responce?

Comment: response.body i get is this [{"No":0,"interest":"0.00","balance":"13,000,000.00","principal":"0.00","Installment":"0.00","Status":true},{"No":1,"interest":"130,000.00","balance":"0.00","principal":"13,000,000.00","Installment":"13,130,000.00","Status":true}]

Comment: but in flutter showing Error FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <br/> Flutter. this is didnt get value from parameter. I'm using http get

Comment: Are you get past the cross origins barrier

Comment: yes if with this http://192.168.0.23/edufund-api/Api/loansimulation.php?periodtime=3&interestpermonth=1&loanamountrequest=10000000 its working fine. With parameter failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `Dio` package and it would be like this:

```
  static Future<LoanResult> simulators(
      {String periodtime,
      String interestpermonth,
      String loanamountrequest,
      String url}) async {
    Dio dio = Dio();
    var url = "http://192.168.0.23/edufund-api/Api/loansimulation.php";
    final response = await dio.get(
      url,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      queryParameters: {
        'periodtime': periodtime,
        'interestpermonth': interestpermonth,
        'loanamountrequest': loanamountrequest
      },
    );

    var res = LoanResult.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);
    print(response.body); //value get in response.body
    return res;
  }
```